# Theming translatable nodes in D7

Tags: 7

We used i18n module to have our nodes as translatable.
However we also themed a specific nid with e.g node--9.tpl.php.

Problem is that i18n *creates separate nodes*(this separate nids), for each translation language, thus the theme file only applies to 1 version of that particular node.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code to `template.php` and clear cache

```
function <THEME_NAME>_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    if(!empty($vars['node']->tnid) && $vars['node']->tnid !== 0){
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__'.$vars['node']->tnid;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'd add that in my case *$vars* was *$variables* and that if you already have the above *preprocess_node* function in your code you should just put the inner code within the already existing function. Thanks, it works like a charm

Comment: I know this is outside the scope of the question, but do you know what happens with blocks that are listed to appear only on particular nodes? How do I cover that scenario?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Please explain in detail or add new question